# How to sum elements of an ArrayList which are values of a HashMap using java streams?

Tags: java, lambda, hashmap, java-stream

I have a HashMap with integer and ArrayList of some Element objects. Element objects are described with price and amount. I want to go through all those elements in each ArrayList, sum them up by calling on each element `element.price()`, and create a new HashMap which contains old keys from and new values representing summ of each arraylist. Keys for new hash map should remain the same. Trying to do this using streams.

```
public static HashMap<Integer, Double> findIncomes(HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Element>> mapa){


    Map<String, Double> m = mapa.entrySet().stream().flatMap()

    return m;
}
```

Comment: A HashMap may not be sorted.

Comment: `HashMap`s cannot be indexed so it makes no sense to sort its elements. If you want a sorted map, consider TreeMap.

Comment: A TreeMap is sorted by key, not by value. You shouldn't use a Map, whatever its type is.

Comment: **HashMap** is implemented as a hash table, and there is no ordering on keys or values.  **TreeMap** is implemented based on red-black tree structure, and it is ordered by the key. **LinkedHashMap** preserves the insertion order. **Hashtable** is synchronized, in contrast to HashMap.

Comment: Why not use a `List` instead of a `Map` in the first place?

Comment: Sorting is not so important as summing up those elements and keep those values under same key, from which arraylist they came from..I hope I'm explaining correctly :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort map by value using lambdas and streams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29567575/sort-map-by-value-using-lambdas-and-streams)

Comment: @TA  Keys in map represent some other objects (in this case `Restaurant`  object )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first solution that came to my mind was to use `mapToDouble` and `sum`.

That would have looked like this:

```
public static HashMap<Integer, Double> findIncomes(HashMap<Integer, List<Element>> mapa) {
    HashMap<Integer, Double> sumsByKey = new HashMap<>();
    mapa.entrySet().stream().forEach(entry -> sumsByKey.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().stream().mapToDouble(element -> element.getPrice()).sum()));
    return sumsByKey;
}
```

But when summing up 1.5d, 5.4d and 6.7d you get 13.600000000000001 as a result.

Therefore I had to remember: When performing calculations with doubles you usually better use `BigDecimal`.

So a more accurate solution could look like this:

```
public static HashMap<Integer, Double> findIncomes(HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Element>> mapa){
    HashMap<Integer, Double> sumsByKey = new HashMap<>();
    mapa.entrySet().stream().forEach(entry -> sumsByKey.put(entry.getKey(),
        entry.getValue().stream().map(element -> BigDecimal.valueOf(element.getPrice())).reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add).doubleValue()));
    return sumsByKey;
}
```

Since stream in stream is not really readable it might make sense to refactor it further.

Comment: Why BigDecimal is necessary for summing?

Comment: @MaS on the 4th line, why are you using `map()`, is it possible to go with `mapToDouble()` ?

Comment: Since I want to map the price of the element to a BigDecimal I can't use mapToDouble.

Comment: Can you explain more on the precision part you are handling with BigDecimal? I'm quite not getting it :-)

Comment: @MaS Ok thanks, I if it is not a problem, what is te purpose of reduce operation in this case? Thank you.

Comment: @Kris Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13093982/java-double-calculation) for more on this issue.

Comment: Sure will do,  Thanks

Comment: @Miljan The reduce-call more or less performs the subsequent add-calls to get a single result (=the sum of).

Answer (score 0):

You need a new map always. You cannot alter the same map with different types. Something like this would do the job,

```
public static HashMap<Integer, Double> findIncomes(HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Element>> mapa) {

        final HashMap<Integer, Double> m = new HashMap<>();
        mapa.entrySet().stream().forEach(entry -> m.put(entry.getKey(), Double.valueOf(entry.getValue().stream().mapToDouble(Element::price).sum())));
        return m;
    }
```